# EveryPlay causing a major Frame Rate dip for our game, has anyone else experienced this?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, frame-rate, everyplay

Hello All  In the app my studio is currently developing we are planning on using Everyplay to help us record and share videos amongst our users .    we ran a major optimization pass where we removed a shader that was giving us performance headaches. when we had the shader the game was running at 40 FPS and when we recorded with Everyplay I recall the frame rate remaining stable .

yet now that we removed this shader and are running at 60 FPS  recording with EveryPlay is dropping our frame rate from 60 FPS to about 20  and once we stop the Everyplay Recording the frame rate rises again to  50 -60 FPS .

Has anyone else had a similar experience or know how to solve this issue ?

Right now we are experimenting with Everyplay on the Android which I know is still a very young SDK and I sent a message to the Everyplay support e-mail as well .

Answer (score 0):

Especially the Android version still has plenty of room for improvements and there's been a few releases now fine-tuning and optimizing the issues.

Most times the performance differences between devices are due different GPU vendors,
Mali/Adreno are working pretty good already. With Nvidia's Tegra, there's still a bunch
of GPU specific optimizations under development but it should work ok for simpler games

UPDATE: As of March 2015, there's now a new SDK 1.3 release out with major graphics performance and stability improvements, especially against Nvidia Tegra's.